# Why does i stand for minutes in the Y-m-d H:i:s time format?

Tags: php, date

This is a pretty simple question, but I cound't find an answer anywhere with various searches. When we have a time format in PHP like  Y-m-d H:i:s it's very easy to understand that:

```
Y = years
m = months
d = days
H = hours
s = seconds
```

But why are minutes represented with "i"? In other words, where does this naming convention come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They couldn't use `m` or `M` for minutes, because they were already used for the month. `m` is a numeric month, and `M` is the month abbreviation.

So they had to use a different letter that's not already assigned. I assume they chose `i` because it's the second letter of `minute`.